# Inconsistent accessibility field type is less accessible than field

Tags: c#

I created User class but when i want to take array of user objects, i face Inconsistent accessibility field type is less accessible than field error
this is my code:

```
namespace CRUD.Model
{
    class User
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
    }
}
namespace CRUD
{
    public partial class PurchasesBill : Form
    {
        public List<User> userList = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are you asking ? What question  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make your `User` class `public`:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

By default, if no access modifier is specified for the given class, it is `internal`.

Answer (score 2):

A `public` class cannot have any publicly visible types (i.e. `public` or `protected` properties or fields) in it that themselves aren't `public`. Your `User` class is publicly visible through your `userlist` field, but the `User` class isn't `public`. Hence the error.